# Как сгенерировать ID для товара? JS

Tags: javascript

Суть такая, есть список для типов продуктов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для каждого типа я указал свой `data-атрибут` типа `data-name="sandwiches"`.

На каждый элемент списка я повесил событие клика с `fetch`, где я делаю выборку из `json` и достаю определенный товар в зависимости от выбранного типа (data-атрибута).

Получается один клик - одна выборка, данные о товаре приходят в таком виде:

```
{
  "name": "Овощной",
  "description": "Соус и овощи на выбор",
  "image": "/i/sandwiches/ovoshnoy.png",
  "price": 105,
  "category": "sandwiches",
  "market": "subway",
  "type": "multiple",
  "weight": 1,
  "components": {
    "size": {},
    "bread": "white-italian",
    "vegetable": [],
    "sauce": [],
    "filling": []
  }
}, 
{
  "name": "Индейка",
  "description": "Сэндвич с индейкой, соус и овощи на выбор",
  "image": "/i/sandwiches/ind.png",
  "price": 130,
  "category": "sandwiches",
  "market": "subway",
  "type": "multiple",
  "weight": 1,
  "components": {
    "size": "1x",
    "bread": "white-italian",
    "vegetable": [],
    "sauce": [],
    "filling": []
  }
}
```

и т.д, порядка 150 наименований.

Проблема в том, что у этих продуктов нет своего ID, а мне их нужно добавлять\удалять в\из корзину\ы.

Я пробовал отталкиваться от имени продукта, но есть продукты, которые могут быть составлены из ингредиентов, соответственно в корзине могут быть продукты с одинаковыми именами (но разным содержимым), и получается чтобы узнать по какому продукту я кликнул, мне нужно отталкиваться от его имени.

А имена могут повторяться и придумывать какие-то велосипеды для проверки содержимого, считаю что это не верно.

Вопрос: как правильно сгенерировать ID самому для каждого продукта после `fetch`.

Напомню, что я сделал один клик - один `fetch`, выборку я ни где не сохраняю, она каждый раз новая, кроме как сохранить в ЛС я больше не знаю как, но использовать ЛС пока не хочу.

Может быть Вы предложите какие-нибудь другие варианты.

Спасибо!

Comment: Куда фетчем ходишь? Это сторонняя апи? Или сам пишешь бэк? Сколько времени на клиенте должно это всё храниться? В общем, тз не очень понятно. В самом просто случае генерь случайное число 0 - 10^9. Ну и можно проверку сделать на всякий случай, чтоб совпадений не возникало. Хотя из миллиарда совпадение получить... я бы в казино поехал ;)

Comment: Да, не уточнил на счет API. извиняюсь) Это моя тренировочная работа, поэтому фетчем я хожу по отдельному файлу json(эмуляция бэка)) и оттуда забираю что мне нужно)) У меня самый простой случай, поэтому "сколько времени на клиенте должно это всё храниться?" - это не учитывается

Comment: Да я хотел получать число через Math.random(), но после подумал: например я выбрал какой-то товар(пусть он будет товар_1), добавил его в корзину(у него свой рандомный id). далее я перешел в какой-то другой тип, там что-нибудь выбрал. после вернулся к первому типу и хочу добавить товар_1 в корзину(но у него уже другой рандомный id) и соответственно в корзине их количество не изменится, а будет лежать два разных товара.

Comment: Так ты можешь считать сколько товаров в корзине просто, без привязки к ID.

Comment: Ну так не бывает. В бд всегда должен быть айдишник. Айдишник на клиенте изобретать, это очень не здоровая тема. Так что не мудри, раз сам делаешь "апи", а просто добавь туда поля с айди. На клиенте айдишник никто никогда не делает. Это не имеет смысла именно потому, что вот такие коллизии, описанные тобой же, могут происходить. Айдишник берётся из базы.

Comment: Да, я конечно же понимаю, что он должен быть там по определению, что он должен быть в базе )) Просто я пытаюсь что-то придумать в своем учебном варианте, как быть в случаи если этого id нет. Написать самому, самый простой и правильный вариант, не получится) Ну я вас понял. благодарю за совет.

Comment: Для товара необходимо сделать уникальный ID в базе, без генераторов, есть вариант делать код товара (уникальный) и брать его из базы, по коду товара потом можно соединить и кассы и 1С к примеру

Comment: Для учебного варианта достаточно добавить поле id или код товара как известное поле в json а не генерировать его, в реальном проекте в любом случае будете брать id или код из базы!

Comment: Можете генерировать id из нескольких полей используя хеш функции, любую (можете даже простую сами написать) Коллизии маловероятны. В качестве полей для хеша можете взять name, description, category.

Comment: Благодарю всех за советы ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы генерировать уникальные ID для каждой позиции товара в момент когда Вы получаете данные можно воспользоваться утилитами типа [uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4).

В этом случае Вам не нужно будет "собирать" ключ из нескольких "полей" (типа name, description, и category) что бы гарантировать его уникальность, вероятность того что он повториться крайне мала.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! да, я читал про этот модуль до публикации моего поста тут. Не хотел ничего стороннего подключать. Интересно было сделать\узнать, как можно было бы сделать генерацию id собственноручно )

Comment: @kostya нет смысла изобретать велосипед, что бы не "тянуть" доп. библиотеку можно просто посмотреть что она делает и ... далее думаю Вы поняли